# Javascript json_encode array of floats

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

In php, I gather geocoords and round them. The results dumped are as expected:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 37.76073
            [1] => -122.439948
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 37.973535
            [1] => -122.531087
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 37.973535
            [1] => -122.531087
        )    
)
```

( The duplicates are also expected. )
Then I pass them into javascript for use on a map:

```
var locations = <?php echo json_encode( $geo_locations ); ?>;
```

But when I log locations to the console, the values have changed for the 2nd element:

```
0: (2) [37.76073, -122.439948]
1: (2) [37.97368106291033, -122.53094093708967]
2: (2) [37.973535, -122.531087]
```

I've never seen this behavior before. Is it due to json_encode? Or something else?

Comment: It seems json_encoders prefer strings. Encoding floats can have "unexpected" results.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't have anything to do with JSON.  It's how floating point numbers are handled in computers.

See also:  [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)